# Win32 Application in C# .Net

Tags: c#, visual-c++, com, wrapper, unmanaged

I have developed a window based application based on Native calls. In this application I am handling lots of mouse events, keyboard hooking, painting etc.

My question is that how can I use that win32 application (Unmanaged) in C# .Net?

I have read about the managed wrapper to wrap up win32 application, if you think this is the best option then please suggest me any book or reference of tutorial which can help me to move forward. Otherwise suggest any other option which you think is best in this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "use in .Net"?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer, just like a custom user controls, I can drag n drop native window on managed window.

Comment: You probably have to wrap that user control as ActiveX to insert it in .NET Windows Form. Alternatively (if you implement is as Window class for example) you can get Windows form HWND (Handle property) and use PInvoke to create child window with Windows API from .NET application.

Comment: @VASoftOnline, have you any refrence book or tutorial which may help in this project?

Comment: If you are familiar with Windows API and/or COM, you can read how to use them from .NET application here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172270.aspx

Answer (score 0):

at least you can use your .dll through COM Interop.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options if you want to 'control' one application from the other, where one is Native and the other is Managed.

Have you cosidered using [named-pipes](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp) to 'control' your application?

Comment: Its not DLL, its window based application which I have to use in C# program.